# How to find the same parts between two text files?

Tags: linux, bash, compare

Here are two text files,A and B both contain multiple word items ,seperated by line breaks or space break.
Now I want to compare A with B,find the same items in the two files,then remove them from A,
in bash.Any good idea?

Comment: You forgot to post what you already tried and where you got stuck.  Also, I don't understand the term "between" in connection with two files.

Comment: did you see _man cmp_

Comment: Thank you guys,and sorry for my poor English^^

Comment: @Alfe sorry,I dont even know where to start.and what do you mean in "don't understand the term "between" in connection with two files"?Did I use the wrong prep word?sorry for my poor English

Comment: If you don't even know where to start, Stackoverflow is not the site for you.  Here you are supposed to be stuck on a specific question.  What you are doing is posting programming tasks.  That's not what SO is meant for.  We strive to give answers to questions _other_ people also might have one day, so we raise the amount of knowledge publicly available.  By solving a programming task this is not achieved.

Comment: @Alfe You say stackoverflow not the site for me,sorry I don't what big man you are,I cant agree with you.I've come here several times and everytime I got what I want,and that's why I choose to come here.If you dont think my foolish question is worth your time,then please just leave my question alone and you don't need to bother yourself to answer it ,please Good bye,big guy,go save the world

Comment: @erical: 1. Have a look at the first point in "Don't ask about..." section in about page. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/about) is the link, for your convenience. 2. If your next question passes all these tests, then ask the question on SO. Else, it is very likely to be closed/deleted/put on hold.

Comment: well,then just let it be.Same words,if you and that Alfe dont want to answer,please just leave silently.Stackoverflow is not your home,OK?Anyway,thank you for the anwers,please dont relpy anymore.go to find your meaning life and those more meaningful question,bro 3^ ^

Comment: Even if we leave, there would be others telling you the same thing (and probably closing your tickets).  Don't take it personally; there just are rules on SO we just tell you about, we don't make them.  We just explain why six people here now voted for closing your ticket.  It's not us.  It's your question.

Comment: Btw, by closing questions like the one you posted we all try to keep the high quality this site has achieved over the last years.  Without such rules, SO would be just one more forum among many.

Comment: what I'm confused about is,why you and that Alfe cant just come inside to answer the foolish question or just tell me "the same thing"?Is it too difficult to leave others alone and to find something meaningful for both yourself?If so,I appologize,otherwise what could I say

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Alfe looks correct one. However, if you are not bothered about the word separator in output file, then this may be optimized solution:

```
grep -w -v -f <(sed 's/[ \n\t]\+/\n/g' A) <(sed '$s/[ \n\t]\+/\n/g' B)
```

If the data in both files is sorted/same sequence, then you can also use `comm`

```
comm -13 <(sed 's/[ \n\t]\+/\n/g' A) <(sed 's/[ \n\t]\+/\n/g' B)
```

Comment: thank you,beside,that I forgot to mention in the main post,what if there are also a few same items in A,and for each item one is enough for me,so I want to find them and remove the extra ones,any command available?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly, so this answer is kinda shot in the dark.

First I would create versions of the files which contain one word each line.  Then I would step through B:

```
while read word; do …; done < B
```

for each in B found word I would remove it from A (that at the … above):

```
sed -i "s/^$word$//" A
```

Maybe that helps.

Comment: sorry,I dont even know where to start.and what do you mean in "don't understand the term "between" in connection with two files"?Did I use the wrong prep word?sorry for my poor English

Comment: You say stackoverflow not the site for me,sorry I don't what big man you are,I cant agree with you.I've come here several times and everytime I got what I want.If you dont think my foolish question is worth your time,then please just leave my question alone and you don't need to bother yourself to answer it ,please^ ^

Comment: I'm sorry if I came over rude or insulting, that was not my intention.  It's just that there are rules in SO which we (try to) stick to.  If questions do not meet them, they get closed.  One such rule is that your question needs to show a minimal understanding on how to solve your issue.  Mere programming tasks just are not the topic here.  There are other sites for this, I guess (but probably they might be commercial).  I'm no "big man".  I'm just the messenger.